# Difference between copy and microcopy, copywriting

Tags: copywriting

I am an UX newbie, but I read a few articles and I keep stumbling upon words copy and microcopy. Can someone tell me what they are? Some practical example would be great. Also what is copywriting?

Comment: Welcome to UX Stack Exchange! Trying to help, there doesn't appear to be much effort put into this question (a Google search should be sufficient to answer this). If you've done some research into the question already, please be more specific on the questions you have. As is, this question is too general.

Comment: well, i tried googling but it wasnt very clear to me. what i found was for more acknowledged person in the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Copywriting is an act of writing content for a post, webpage etc.
The text, in general, is referred as copy.

Microcopy: Texts which are present in the application. Example: Error message, Forms